# Acessing GPIOs with pypylon

Tags: python, camera

I am using the Basler Racer raL2048-48gm camera and need to access the GPIOS via pypylon API (pylon for python ). I'm used to programming in c ++ version of pylon, there to access a GPIO from a camera you write something like this:

```
// some code ....
Camera_t Camera (pTl-> CreateDevice (info1));
Camera.UserOutputSelector.SetValue (UserOutputSelector_UserOutput2);
Camera.UserOutputValue.SetValue (true);
// some code ....
```

I didn't find anything in the pypylon API that would allow me to access the camera's GPIOS ... Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I was not calling camera.open() before trying to access the camera parameters. [More info](https://github.com/basler/pypylon/issues/192).

Thanks everyone that tried answer this question.